# Is there a limit to the number of tasks?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, task

I am running a winrt program with multiple tasks. 
In the middle of running, I get the following exception:

```
Not enough quota is available to process this command
```

The stack trace is

```
   at Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher.InvokeAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority priority, InvokedHandler freeThreadedCallback, Object sender, Object context)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.InvokeOrPostAction(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunInline(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__1(Object s)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Then it crashes.

Is this a problem specific to WintRT?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Share some code? I believe by running an application in debug mode you can see where exception was thrown

Comment: Remember that .Net tasks run on a synchronization context.  In your case, the synchronization context is the UI thread (you see this because it's calling CoreDispatcher.InvokeAsync).  That means that all your tasks are going to run serially on the UI thread.  Is that whatyou intended?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the MSDN documentation for that error message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms820778.aspx), the fix for that error is to either "close some applications" or "increase the size of your paging file".

Given that, you might want to start by looking in Task Manager and see if your application is using a totally unreasonable amount of memory (or if some other process is). If your process has a memory leak, it might lead to this problem.